# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(⌊n / 2⌋)?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

What is the order of the function

T(n)=1  , n=1

T(n)=T(floor(n/2))  , n>1

I am doubt because there's no any glue functions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you forgot an `+O(1)` or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

This solves to T(n) = 1. You can prove this by contradiction; suppose there's some number n where T(n) ≠ 1. Let n<sub>0</sub> be the least number with this property. Then n<sub>0</sub> can't be 1, because we know T(1) = 1. So that means that n<sub>0</sub> > 1. But since T(n<sub>0</sub>) = T(⌊n<sub>0</sub> / 2⌋), that means that T(⌊n<sub>0</sub> / 2⌋) ≠ 1 as well. However, since n<sub>0</sub> > 1, we know that ⌊n<sub>0</sub> / 2⌋ < n<sub>0</sub>, contradicting the fact that n<sub>0</sub> is the least choice of n for which T(n) ≠ 1. Since we have a contradiction, we know that T(n) must always be 1.

Hope this helps!